# How do you add a custom ITraceWriter to Newtonsoft JSON in ASP.NET Core Startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I want to add a custom trace writer to help with debugging JSON calls. I have implemented an `ITraceWriter` class but can find no documentation on how to add it to this call.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()
```

And the object

```
public class JSONTraceWriter : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ITraceWriter
{
    public TraceLevel LevelFilter
    {
        get
        {
            return TraceLevel.Error;
        }
    }

    TraceLevel ITraceWriter.LevelFilter => TraceLevel.Error;


    public void Trace(TraceLevel level, string message, Exception ex)
    {
        SiAuto.Main.LogMessage($"JSONTraceWriter: {message}");
        SiAuto.Main.LogException("JSONTracerWriter", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom trace writer by setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.TraceWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_TraceWriter.htm) in [`MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions.SerializerSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcnewtonsoftjsonoptions.serializersettings?#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions_SerializerSettings) when calling [`AddNewtonsoftJson(this IMvcCoreBuilder, Action<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.newtonsoftjsonmvccorebuilderextensions.addnewtonsoftjson?#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_NewtonsoftJsonMvcCoreBuilderExtensions_AddNewtonsoftJson_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IMvcCoreBuilder_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions__):

```cs
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.TraceWriter = new JSONTraceWriter();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you - I knew it would be something like that.